# Are all the transaction controllers present in a thread group executed concurrently

Tags: jmeter

This is how the test script is designed. One thread group has multiple transaction controllers. Under each transaction controller there is a GraphQL request.
My question is say this test is executed for 500 threads so will all the requests under different transaction controllers be executed simultaneously i.e. will Request 1, Request 2 and Request 3 be executed concurrently[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMjSR.png)

Answer (score 0):

It depends, each JMeter thread (virtual user) executes [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) or in your case [Transaction Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) containing Samplers upside down and waits for the previous response before executing the next request.

If you have 500 concurrent users there is a chance that requests 1-3 will be executed at the same time, but they will be executed by different users.

In case you need to execute all 3 requests at the same time by 1 user - put them under [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter)